# google map does not visible

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

here is my log cat out put

```
05-03 13:14:38.495: E/AndroidRuntime(4157): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }

05-03 13:21:03.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4209): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
```

google play service is not update  what i have to do

Comment: post the relevant codes

Comment: You cannot use emulator to test GMaps API v2. Are you using it by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

If the device lacks the Play Store -- which your error logs indicate -- then the device cannot use Maps V2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you need to use a **real device** to see Google map,not in **emulator**.
Then,your device should have **Google Play Service** to view the map.If it doesn't then install Google Play Service in your device. Or,if your device has **Google Play Store** app installed,then update it to get services of Google Play.
If the problem still doesn't solve,then you need to share your code with us here..